# Magento 2 Get Tier Price of Group while user not logged in

Tags: magento2

I try to get a tier price for a certain customer group in Magento 2.
The tier price should be shown on webshop even if a user  is **not** logged in (and thus not a member of the group at that time)
This tier price is for members only. But to encourage visitors to become a member, the member price and the regular (final) must be visible.
I'm overwriting Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\RendererPool.

I can get the minimal Tier Price for a configurable product with this group like this:

```
private function getMemberPrice(Product $product)
{
    if ($product->getTypeId() == 'configurable') {
        $om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $configurable = $om->get('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable');
        $children = $configurable->getUsedProducts($product);
        /**
         * @var  $childKey
         * @var Product $child
         */
        $minimalTierMemberPrice = null;
        foreach ($children as $childKey => $child) {

            $tier_prices = $child->getTierPrices();
            if ($tier_prices && count($tier_prices) > 0) {
                foreach ($tier_prices as $tier_price) {
                    if ($tier_price->getCustomerGroupId() == 4 /* MEMBER CUSTOMER GROUP ID */) {
                        if (!$minimalTierMemberPrice || $minimalTierMemberPrice->getValue() > $tier_price->getValue()) {
                            $minimalTierMemberPrice = $tier_price;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if ($minimalTierMemberPrice) {
            return $minimalTierMemberPrice;
        } else {
            return $this->getNonMemberPrice($product);
        }
    }

    //if none member price was set, return the memberprice
    return $this->getNonMemberPrice($product);
}
```

After that I try to override createPriceRender to generate the block with template.
I try to wrap my head around for several days now. That's why I'm trying to push my minimal tier price in the FinalPriceBox / final_price.phtml template as in this code:

```
 public function createPriceRender(
    $priceCode,
    SaleableInterface $saleableItem,
    array $data = []
)
{
    if (isset($data['special_price']) && $data['special_price'] == 'member_price') {
        $renderClassName = FinalPriceBox::class;
        $blockTemplate = 'Magento_Catalog::product/price/final_price.phtml';

        $product = $this->getProduct($saleableItem->getId());

        $price = $this->getMemberPrice($product);
        //$price = $saleableItem->getPriceInfo()->getPrice($priceCode);
        //$price = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price');

        $arguments['data'] = $data;
        $arguments['rendererPool'] = $this;
        $arguments['price'] = $price;
        $arguments['saleableItem'] = $saleableItem;
        //$arguments['member_price'] = true;

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template $renderBlock */
        $renderBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock($renderClassName, '', $arguments);


        if (!$renderBlock instanceof PriceBoxRenderInterface) {

            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
                'Block "' . $renderClassName . '" must implement \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\PriceBoxRenderInterface'
            );
        }
        $renderBlock->setTemplate($blockTemplate);

        return $renderBlock;

    } else {
        //original code here
        return parent::createPriceRender($priceCode, $saleableItem, $data);
    }
}
```

I get following error when I try this

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 3 passed to Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox\Interceptor::__construct() must implement interface Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\PriceInterface, instance of Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\TierPrice given
```

It's quite clear what's the error about. But anyway I want to get my tier price, but with the priceinterface implemented (as the original Rendererpool gets for final prices etc.)

Should I get my tier prices in another way?